# What set is this piece used for

Tags: part-identification

i have a Lego from the 80s. I can see there are space pieces in grey and blue. I am wondering if this piece is for a space set and if so which one. Any help much appreciated!![image]

Comment: Welcome Tina. Do these pieces have a LEGO marking on them somewhere? At first glance they look like another brick-building brand, not like LEGO.

Answer (score 23):

These are [Panel 4 x 4 x 6 Corner Convex Ribbed](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4737)

They were mainly use as decorative pieces on corners in classic space sets.

In light grey they came only in one Set: [Solar Power Transporter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6952-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image: 6952 Solar Power Transporter]
(photo from Bricklink)

Comment: Ahhh this post brings back memories...

Comment: Thanks so much! That is very helpful as I also recognise the other pieces in the photo as something in my mix drawer.

Comment: @Tina You can press the check mark next to the 1uestion to tell that this answer has been suitable for you. It doesn't necessarily mean that it's the best answer, though.